# Orchard CMS - .AtHead() nor Script.Head() Not calling javascript files in Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I am still very new to Orchard CMS and am trying to get several JavaScript files to load in the header. I have tried using both .AtHead() and Script.Head() with no success. The files are only called in the footer of the site.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.  Here is an example of how I have formatted the code:

```
@{ Script.Require("jQuery").AtHead();
 Script.Include("/Themes/MyTheme/Scripts/jquery.collapser.js").AtHead();
 }
```

As well as:

```
@using (Script.Head()) {
 Script.Require("jQuery");
 Script.Include("/Themes/MyTheme/Scripts/jquery.collapser.js");
 }
```

The calls for these files are located in both layout.cshtml and HeadScript.cshtml.  I have tried modifying both with no luck. Using .AtHead() results in the file not being called at all. Using @using (Script.Head()) the files show up in the footer.  I am working with a theme someone else designed and am not sure why they are being called in both locations.

Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Script.Require("myScript").AtHead()` should be the correct syntax to place an external script in the `<head>` section. The `@using(Script.Head())` helper is only to place `<script>` tags in the head, it won't have any effect on the `Require()` and `Include()`

Comment: Also, checkout this thread of why it is included in the footer instead of the head section: http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/285396

Comment: @devqon Thank you for your help.  I have updated the code to be:
@{ Script.Require("jQuery").AtHead();
 Script.Include("/Themes/MyTheme/Scripts/jquery.collapser.js").AtHead(); }
I have also read over the link you provided and went through all the files in the theme to ensure nowhere else was the JQuery being called.  Still no luck.  The jquery.collapser.js is only being called in 1 location and is not showing up with I added .AtHead().

Comment: When using the `.Include()` method you must make sure there is a valid web.config in the scripts folder where your script is. Orchard does not allow direct access by default, so include a web.config that allows the inclusion.

Comment: @devqon. Thank you for the quick reply. There is a web.config file within the scripts folder.  If i do not include the `.AtHead()` at the end of the code to call the JavaScript, the file loads in the footer.  When I add `.AtHead()`, it does not show up at all. Is there something that should be within the web.config file to be able to use the .AtHead()?

Comment: Do you have a `@Display(Model.Head)` in your Document.cshtml?

Comment: Yes there is. This is the code around it `<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@Html.Title(title, siteName)</title> 
    @Display(Model.Head)
</head>`